# datetime.strptime raises valueError because of format mismatch

Tags: python, python-datetime, strptime

I am trying to parse a string to a datetime field but it raises the following error:

```
ValueError: time data '15 Dec 1995 00:00 AM' does not match format '%d %b %Y %I:%M %p'
```

I have checked the [python documents](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) and I don't see where the format mismatch is happening.
Can anyone help me find where this format error is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the docs:

> %I 
> Hour (12-hour clock) as a zero-padded decimal number. 
> 01, 02, …, 12

So `00:00:00` is not a valid time under the `%I` format, given that `00:00:00 AM` should actually be `12:00:00 PM`

Answer (score 1):

There is no 00:00 time in 12-hour clock format, you should either write this as 12:00 or use a 24-hour format with %H.